# ORA-00600 internal error code, arguments kcrfrgv_scn1

Tags: oracle11g

Actually my db got shut down when my pc powered of improperly due to cut of electricity. After that I started up the DB and My DB state has been changed to mounted I wanted to change it back to open mode when entering the " alter database open"  command the following error happened as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: That is an internal oracle error and you need to contact oracle support

Comment: ORA-00600 always means you have to contact Oracle support. But Oracle 11 isn't supported any longer, so unless your company pays a huge amount of money for extended support, you won't be lucky with that either.